# Using proxy with selenium and scrapy implementation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a spider that seeks to use selenium as well as a proxy. The main goal is to make the spider as rigid as possible in avoiding getting caught for webscraping. I know that scrapy has the module 'scrapy-rotating-proxies' but I'm having trouble verifying that scrapy would check the status of the chromedriver's success in requesting a webpage and if it fails due to getting caught then run the process of switching the proxy.

Second, I am somewhat unsure of how a proxy is handled by my computer. For example, if in any case when I set a proxy value is this value consistent for anything that makes a request on my computer? Ie. will scrapy and webdriver have the same proxy values as long as one of them sets the value? Especially if scrapy has a proxy value, will any selenium webdriver instantiated inside of the class definition inherit that proxy?

I'm quite inexperienced with these tools and would really appreciate some help!

I've tried looking for a method to test and check the proxy value of selenium as well as scrapy to compare

```
#gets the proxies and sets the value of the scrapy proxy list in settings
def get_proxies():
        url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
        response = requests.get(url)
        parser = fromstring(response.text)
        proxies = set()
        for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
            if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
                #Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
                proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0],i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
                proxies.add(proxy)

        proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)


        url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
        new_proxy_list = []
        for i in range(1,30):
            #Get a proxy from the pool
            proxy = next(proxy_pool)

            try:
                response = requests.get(url,proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy})

                #Grab and append proxy if valid
                new_proxy_list.append(proxy)



            except:
                #Most free proxies will often get connection errors. You will have retry the entire request using another proxy to work. 
                #We will just skip retries as its beyond the scope of this tutorial and we are only downloading a single url 
                print("Skipping. Connnection error")

#add to settings proxy list
        settings.ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = new_proxy_list
```

Comment: Is the question how to get and check free proxies? Take a look at proxybroker

Comment: Its how to make sure selenium is using the value from the free proxies function and be updated by the scrapy-rotating-proxies library

Comment: Selenium can't change it's proxy once it starts. You would need a proper proxy rotator for that.

Comment: This is why 3,5, 15 minute rotators exist for selenium...or other long sessions.